# Autohotkey: Using a 3 key combination to initiate script?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

Basically I want to find a solution to make this code work by initiating it with b+down+right key combination.

```
~b & Left & Down::                                                                 
{
    BlockInput On
    Click, Left, 1 
    sleep, % _ran(150, 250)
    Click, Rel 144, 72 Left, 1
    sleep, % _ran(150, 250)
    Click, Rel 144, 72 Left, 1
    Click, Right
    BlockInput Off
}
return
```

The code works if I just switch it to ~b & left or ~b & down but the problem is with my brain and I need a 3 key combo.

Basically my monitor is a square (obviously) so the "up" would indicate clicking upwards, down for downwards and so on. But I'm using this scripts within a tilted square and it's hard to differentiate between down left and down right when I just use ~b & down.

The square on the outside is the monitor, the titled square inside is where I'm using the script and need a 3 key combination:

[image: The square on the outside is the monitor, the titled square inside is where I'm using the script and need a 3 key combination]

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out.

```
        ~Right::
      If GetKeyState("b", "b") && GetKeyState("Up", "b") 
      {
            BlockInput On
            Click, Left, 1 
            sleep, % _ran(150, 250)
            Click, Rel 144, 72 Left, 1
            sleep, % _ran(150, 250)
            Click, Rel 144, 72 Left, 1
            Click, Right
            BlockInput Off
      }
      return
```